# Why doesn't this for loop read this in passed argument properly?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Below is my code

```
function generateGrid(spacing, boundBox, geometry) {
    console.log(spacing);
    console.log(boundBox);
    var grid = [];
    console.log(spacing);
    for (var x = boundBox[0]; x < boundBox[2]; x = x + spacing) {
        for (var y = boundBox[1]; y < boundBox[3]; y = y + spacing) {
            if(geometry.intersectsCoordinate([x, y])) grid.push([x, y]);
            console.log(boundBox[3] - y)
        }
        console.log(boundBox[1] - x)
    }
    console.log(grid);
}
```

[image: console output]

If `spacing` is replaced by a number like `10000` the for loop executes fine.

Comment: whats your expected outcome?

Comment: @Workion provided an answer, I'm now waiting for the cool down to end.

Comment: To answer your question: the `x` and `y` steppers should increase by the amount `spacing` is set to, i.e.: `10000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your Console screenshot it looks like the passed in argument is the string `"10000"` rather than the number `10000`.

Either check the code that's calling your function, or convert to an integer inside the function, for example by using `parseInt(spacing)`.

As a tip to help with spotting any similar issues in the future, Chrome's `console.log` shows numeric values in blue and string values in black.

Comment: [Other options for coercing a string to number](https://jsperf.com/best-of-string-to-number-conversion/37).

Answer (score 1):

x is a number so use String(x) so you use operator + between two strings, that would give you "15" + "1" = "151", but that is probably not what you wanted

Comment: Damn, should've checked for this. Thanks.

Comment: Clarifying for others as the wording was a bit off for me. When you concatenate a number and string together you get a string. Since `spacing` is a string and `x` is some number, let's say `10`, then `x + spacing = 10 + "10000" = "1010000"`.